# How to execute code from php file when ajax called

Tags: javascript, php

Okay so i have php code which is supposed to check if there is an existing user in database when login is attempted and send back to javascript fail or success

Php code:

```
<?php 

require_once 'Korisnik.php';
require_once 'dbconn/korisnikdb.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    // collect value of input field

    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

    $korisnik = getKorisnikByUserPass($username, $password);

    if ($korisnik == null) {
        $statusArray = array("status"=>"fail");
        echo json_encode($statusArray);
        return;
    } else {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["prijavljeniKorisnik"] = $username;

        $statusArray = array("status"=>"success");
        echo json_encode($statusArray);
        return;
    }
  }

?>
```

Here i have my javascript code :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var usernameInput = $('#usernameInput');
    var passwordInput = $('#passwordInput');
    var pogresniPodaci = $('#pogresniPodaci');
    var praznaPolja = $('#praznaPolja');
    pogresniPodaci.hide();
    praznaPolja.hide();

    $('#submitButton').on('click', function(event) {
        var username = usernameInput.val();
        var password = passwordInput.val(); 

        console.log(username);
        console.log(password);


        if (username == '' || password == '') {
            praznaPolja.show();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        var params = {
            'username': username, 
            'password': password
        }
        $.post('loginCheck.php', params, function(data) { 

            console.log(data.status);

            if (data.status == 'fail') {
                pogresniPodaci.show();
                usernameInput.val('');
                passwordInput.val('');
                return;
            }
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                location.href = 'pocetna';
            }
        });

        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://prntscr.com/skb37r -> here you can see status after i press that button

The problem is that php code in loginCheck.php never actually executes, I tried adding echo at start of php file but it doesn't execute.

Comment: None of the samples I've just looked at put the parameter element names in your `params` declaration in quotes. But I am not well up on JS to know whether that's optional.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending http request to localhost. Even if file doesn't exist, your localhost will return status 200, unless it's configured to throw an error.

Try this:
go to http://localhost/loginCheck.php and echo anything there.

```
echo "This is loginCheck";
```

If it echoes, you are on the right route to loginCheck file.
If it works, go to browser dev tools > network >  and see request headers and find "Request URL" header. it should be "http://localhost/loginCheck.php" - the route to file you visited previously. if its not, you have to fix it in $.post request.

Comment: It just shows same login page from my login.php which is not supposed to do. Actual location should be http://localhost/phppractice/loginCheck.php and in request url it shows that exact adress - >  http://prntscr.com/skbzdg

Comment: localhost/phppractice/loginCheck.php shows login form from 'login.php"?